# How to create a quiz using sharepoint list? OOTB only version 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created a list of around 443 items 
I have set item limit to 1 so that it shows one item at a time
Now to create a quiz

I need to know how do i show the random items in sharepoint list and how to create a column whic user will fill and submit the answers.

Then sharepoint column will check using that column whether the answer is right or not

Comment: *how do i show the random items [...] and how to [...]* by doing some searches and writting some code. That's harsh, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Survey may not suit your case.

Because the rating/grading functionality would be very difficult to address with Surveys. I'd also recommend you to create ASP.NET pages, but create them as application pages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732.aspx

After creating this page just deploy to _LAYOUTs and call this page into your web part page. I've a different thought of using PageViewer web part. Do not use page viewer webpart for this kind of quiz functionality. If you have a single plain vannila page, you can go for page viewer web part. Quiz would be a full-blown ASP.NET web application. Its' better to deploy that as application page instead of a page viewer web part approach.

If you ready to purchase 3'rd party products, you can try evaluating the following web part.
http://www.click2learn.ch/quiz/default.aspx

Comment: Hi Sree,thanks but May I know is there any way with OOTB

Comment: Hi Karan,Good day.. With the current versions of sharepoint not included this as an out of the box functionality. We need to create this as a seperate function.

Comment: http://sharepointquiz.blogspot.com/?m=1.   This link is explaining detailed development process. I hope this links will help you